# My Add-On was approved by Google, but it is available only to members of my employer's domain

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-addons, google-apps-script-add-on

I developed an add-on for Google spreadsheets, have sent it over to Google for a review, and after much blood, toil, tears and sweat, had it successfully approved.

Yet, the add-on is only available to members on my employer's domain - a domain that uses Google tools and services (mail services are Gmail based, for example). My employer and I want it to be available to anyone with a Google account. When I contacted Google on the issue, they have sent me a link to a support page in which there are departments of support. My inquiry fits none of them.

Could any of you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

### Publish a Google Add-on to the G Suite Marketplace

### Basic Concepts:

- You must use the G Suite Marketplace SDK in order to get to the
  “Publish” section for publishing an add-on, and you must first open
  the Google Cloud Platform for your specific project (apps script
  file)
- The G Suite Marketplace SDK must be enabled in the Google Cloud
  Platform
- The two sections you need to focus on are:
- 1) Configuration
- 2) Publish
- Two images are required:
- 1) 128px by 128px
- 2) 32px by 32px
- Scopes define what the user will be asked to authorize
- Visibility can be either:
- 1) Public
- 2) My Domain

### Access the Google Cloud Platform:

- From the Apps Script code editor for the project (file) you want to
  publish
- Click the **“Resources”** menu, and then click the **Cloud Platform
  project** menu item
- Click the blue link with the project name and the project ID
- Open the Navigation menu
- Click “API’s and Services

### Enable the G Suite Marketplace SDK

- If you have not already enabled the G Suite Marketplace SDK
- From the Google Cloud Platform
- Click **“Enable APIs and Services"**
- Search “G Suite”
- Click G Suite Marketplace SDK
- Enable the API

### Configure the Add-on settings:

- From the list of API’s click the row for G Suite Marketplace SDK
- Click the wrench / configuration nav menu item
- Enable individual install, which should be checked by default.  Make sure
  it’s checked if you want to provide the add-on to users outside of the
  domain
- Visibility - Public or My Domain
- 1) Public - Anyone outside of the domain
- 2) My Domain - only users in your organization can see the listing in
  the store and install it

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but all the settings for the project are exactly as you suggested. Any other ideas?

Comment: Add-ons in the Chrome Web Store will be migrated to the G Suite Marketplace.  Maybe because things are in transition, it's not working correctly.  It could be a bug. 
 There are only two visibility options for the G Suite Marketplace, *Public* or *My Domain*.  If it's set to Public, then it should be available outside of the domain.  Even if the old Chrome Web Store listing is set to a visibility option of "Unlisted" outside users should still be able to install the add-on from the Chrome Web Store listing.  Unlisted means you can't find it through a search, but you can give them the link.

Comment: We have a progress: indeed I can use a direct link to my app, but after attempting to use it with a Gmail account, a most unexpected thing happens: I get to install the app on my spreadsheet, but when I choose "Add-ons" in the menu, I can locate the name of my project, but the sub-menu contains only a Help option, instead of the title appearing in "function onOpen(e)" in the code.

Comment: Ok, it seems my project is a container-bound script which means it is associated with a specific file on my Google drive. I need it to be a standalone script, which is a different beast that requires the use of a completely new API to interact with files. Am I right?

Comment: It's better to use a stand alone script for an add-on.  You don't need a completely new API.  You can use the `.getActive_???()` method in a stand alone script installed as an add-on.  The code will get the active file that the add-on is installed on.